# Cannot build executable jar using maven-jar-plugin when migrating to java 9 modules

Tags: maven, java-9, java-module, maven-jar-plugin

I am introducing java 9 modules to a big project and I am facing an issue when trying to build an executable JAR (on one of the sub module) using the maven-jar-plugin.
Here is a small view of my project:

```
├───my-sub-module
│   ├───pom.xml
│   └───src
│       ├───main
│       │   └───java
│       │       ├───com
│       │       │   └───packages
│       │       │       └───...
│       │       │           
│       │       └───module-info.java (let's say the module name is com.foo.bar)
│       └───test
│           └───java
│               └───com
│                   └───packages
│                       └───benchmark
│                           └───BenchmarkTests.java
└───pom.xml
```

The plugin configuration in my pom is :

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Build an executable test JAR -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.packages.benchmark.BenchmarkTests</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**EDIT**
When building using `mvn clean install` I got the following stack-trace:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: Could not create modular JAR file. The JDK jar tool exited with 1
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarToolModularJarArchiver.postCreateArchive (JarToolModularJarArchiver.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive (AbstractArchiver.java:1066)
    at org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.createArchive (MavenArchiver.java:676)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.jar.AbstractJarMojo.createArchive (AbstractJarMojo.java:276)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.jar.AbstractJarMojo.execute (AbstractJarMojo.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

I also noticed the following message in maven logs:

```
jar: Package com.package.benchmark missing from ModulePackages class file attribute
```

Does it mean that my test package should have the same name as in the module packages ?

Comment: anything more than that with `-X` flag?

Comment: Why do you want to build an executables jar from test code? Second if you like to build with modules is the question why an executable which combines several module which in consequence will kill any module definition because the jar can only have a single module-info.java...

Comment: @khmarbaise executable jars are for thee purpose of benchmarking and collecting results when running on non physically available machines. For your second question, I am not getting your point. I don't see any reason why I should define a module-package.info for the test if that's your question.

Comment: Benchmarks have different dependencies like (jmh...) which usual unit tests don't have which means best to have a separate module. Creating an executable means having a single jar which in result means only a single module-info can be put into the jar... Furthermore creating a jar which is a module means that all other dependencies have to be a module as well... Also via jmh it's usually best to define the main class to be executed via command line to have several benchmarks within a single jar...

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside many of @khmarbaise's excellent points:

The error:

```
jar: Package com.package.benchmark missing from ModulePackages class file attribute
```

…comes from the `jar --update` operation that the Plexus Archiver executes to make your project's `.jar` file a modular `.jar` file.

One of the flags the Plexus Archiver passes to `jar` is `--main-class`. Because of a [line in the Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.27), the class name supplied as a value for this argument must be a class from the current module, i.e. the module described by the `module-info.class` file at the root of the `.jar` file in question. For perhaps a number of reasons, `jar` decides that `com.packages.benchmark.BenchmarkTests` does not belong to this current module.

The "`ModulePackages class file attribute`" portion of the error message is showing up as a result of `jar` trying to see what known packages there are in the current `module-info.class` class file. The `ModulePackages` attribute of that `module-info.class` file does not contain `com.package.benchmark`.

(The Plexus Archiver could probably output a better error message here and even avoid the `--update` command entirely if it detects a "bad" `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` `Main-Class` attribute, since it has all the same information the `jar` tool does. See https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-archiver/issues/310.)